# How to toggle to show and hide in elements in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

how to expand the elements present inside li . I used toggle on selected

I tried to add a default propertied selected false then onClick of the `li` I ensures if the values matches then selected should be true and displays that particular section ,and onClick of same it should collapse

Is it possible to open always the first dropdown remaining should be closed and when clicked other it open another li dropdown.

Currently onClick is not working

Here is  my code
[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-hodgkin-gfkmg?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const filterAddition = X.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    menus: item.menus.map((items) => ({
      ...items,
      selected: false
    }))
  }));

  const handleOnClick = (event) => {
    filterAddition.map((item) => {
      item.menus.map((items) => {
        if (items.El=== event.target.value) {
          return {
            ...items,
            selected: !item.selected
          };
        }
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <nav className="animated bounceInDown">
        {filterAddition.map(({ menus }, idx) => {
          return menus.map(({ El, subSection, selected }, idx) => (
            <ul key={idx}>
              <li className="sub-menu" value={El} onClick={handleOnClick}>
                <a href="#settings">
                  {El}
                  <div class="fa fa-caret-down right"></div>
                </a>
                {selected && (
                  <ul>
                    {subSection.map(({ E }, i) => (
                      <li key={E}>
                        <a href="#settings">{E}</a>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </li>
            </ul>
          ));
        })}
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are not returning back anything in your first `.map()`, also not in all cases in the second one. Maybe there is the issue. I would take a look at how `.filter()` or `.forEach()` works for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So much to change.

- First, you have to use `useState` to make component reactive when data is change.
- Second, `onClick` have to change.
- Third, try to read documentation especially about react hooks, state and lifecycle.

see this https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-cloud-9mco1?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const X = [
  {
    detail1: "FirstJob",
    menus: [
      {
        Order: 1,
        El: " Record Management",
        subSection: [
          {
            E: "Check  Notification",
            Order: "CheckNotification"
          },
          {
            E: "Check  Record",
            Order: "CheckRecord"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Order: 2,
        El: "Management",
        subSection: [
          {
            E: "Notification",
            Order: "Notification"
          },
          {
            E: "Check",
            Order: "Check"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(X);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filterAddition = X.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      menus: item.menus.map((items) => ({
        ...items,
        selected: false
      }))
    }));
    setState(filterAddition);
  }, []);

  const handleOnClick = (label) => {
    const temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
    for(let i in temp) {
      const menus = temp[i].menus; 
      for(let j in menus) {
        const item = temp[i].menus[j];
        if(item.El === label) {
          item.selected = !item.selected;
        }
      }
    }
    setState(temp);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <nav className="animated bounceInDown">
        {state.map(({ menus }, idx) => {
          return menus.map(({ El, subSection, selected }, idx) => (
            <ul key={idx}>
              <li className="sub-menu" value={El} onClick={() => handleOnClick(El)}>
                <a href="#settings">
                  {El}
                  <div className="fa fa-caret-down right"></div>
                </a>
                {selected && (
                  <ul>
                    {subSection.map(({ E }, i) => (
                      <li key={E}>
                        <a href="#settings">{E}</a>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </li>
            </ul>
          ));
        })}
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```